# Fret buzz-Harmony H22

Tags: maintenance, bass-guitar, buzz

So I've been trying to look at ways to find fix fret buzz on my Harmony H22 bass guitar; it doesn't have a whole lot of buzz and I find it be on multiple frets. I'm not sure if it's just me or if it needs to be readjusted.

Answer (score 1):

As you have buzz at more than one fret, the problem isn't down to one fret, but down to the action. Everyone has different preferences for action on a guitar, but the lower the action the more likely it is you will get fret buzz.

Your options are to change the neck relief, raise the bridge, or raise the nut.

- If the buzzing is worse as you go up the neck, raising the bridge is a quick and easy way to improve things.
- If it's worst at lower frets, raising the nut (or in reality replacing the nut with one that is less worn) will help, but requires a bit more effort.
- Altering the neck relief changes the overall curve of the neck, so will improve buzz in the middle of the neck.

We have quite a few questions here on buzz, and on altering action. Please have a read through them for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Dr Mayhem's post covers fret buzz that occurs within specific regions of the neck. If the buzzing is on random frets for random strings then the issue could be with worn or unseated frets. You've not stated whether your H22 is a reissue or a vintage original, but even a new bass could have potentially uneven fret-heights along the neck.

The other issue is that a certain level of fret buzz is tolerable, depending on the stirngs you are using. I use flatwound strings generally, but set up a bass with Rotosound roundwounds prior to selling it. I was reminded of the buzz you can get from roundwounds if you dig in aggressively. This buzz doesn't always translate into the tone of your bass when it is plugged in.

Comment: I am honestly not sure whether it is original or not, I found this bass in my grandfather's attic; being that he is 75+ makes me believe it is actually an original. Plus, those strings have been on there for a couple months.

Comment: I want to say they've been on here for 3 maybe 4 months

Comment: If the neck attaches with bolts then it is an original '60s Harmony, and if the neck is glued in then it is a reissue.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I have an original; there are 3 big Phillips-head screws located on the back near the neck.